# How to make a generated 'sum of row' column in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, rowwise

I'm trying to create a table in SQLite that contains a text column, several integer columns, and a final column that is the sum of all integers in that row.

This is my attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE example1(name TEXT,
                      num1 INT,
                      num2 INT,
                      num3 INT,
                      num_total REAL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (num1 + num2 + num3));
```

And the error message is

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: near "AS": syntax error
At line 1:
CREATE TABLE example1(name TEXT,
                      num1 INT,
                      num2 INT,
                      num3 INT,
                      num_total REAL GENERATED ALWAYS AS
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using?  This capability was added in 3.31.0.

Comment: I am using version 3.31.1,  so I guess it should be there

Comment: . . The error that you are getting is the error you would get if it were not supported.  And the code works where it is supported.  You can run `select sqlite_version()` just to verify the version.

Comment: You were right! Tried it in SQL server rather than SQLite and it worked- I just had to put in an ID column. Thanks!